# derivative of a vector with a smooth curve

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to show that $r'= \frac{t' \cdot t}{r}$ with t as the position of the vector and r as the length of the vector. How can I ever prove that? Can somebody give me a hint or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $r = \vert t \vert = \sqrt{t \cdot t}$. Differentiating gives $$ r' = \frac{(t\cdot t)'}{2\sqrt{t\cdot t}} = \frac{(t\cdot t)'}{2r}.$$ Now what is left for you to do is to show that $(t\cdot t)' = 2 t'\cdot t$. (Hint: The dot product is bilinear so use the multivariable chain rule to show $(t\cdot t)' = t'\cdot t + t\cdot t' = 2t'\cdot t$)

Answer (score 0):

An ever so slightly nicer solution to William's could be to try
$(r^2)' = 2 r r'$, but $r^2 = t\cdot t$, so $(r^2)' = (t \cdot t)' = 2 t \cdot t'$. This gives $t \cdot t' = r r'$, and the result you're looking for. Ultimately this is the same as William's, but you don't have to differentiate square roots, and this technique can occasionally make work cleaner.